# jQuery: Change plugin option after called

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've a plugin made by my own to set up a few things when using dialog of jquery-ui. Instead of calling:

```
$("#popup").dialog(options);
```

I use this:

```
$("#popup").dialogPlugin(options);
```

And dialogPlugin will call  `.dialog(options)` (after doing some stuff).

In my plugin I may modify some functions for the events of the dialog like this:

```
var originalCloseFn = options.close;
options.close = function() {
    //my own stuff.
    originalCloseFn();
};
```

The plugin works great, but after some time using it I realized that I couldn't change the dialog functions from outside the plugin like this:

```
$("#popup").dialog("option", "close", newFunctionOnClose);
```

If I do that the code the plugin added to the close function would be lost.

So I added this code at the beggining of my plugin:

```
if (options == "option") {
    if (val == undefined)
        return _this.dialog("option", name);
    else
        return _this.dialog("option", name, val);
}
```

Now I need to change the fifth line of this code to actually change the option of my plugin, not of the jquery-ui. (The option of `.dialogPlugin` function, not of `.dialog`). I realy don't know how can I do that. Any ideas please?

**Edit**

I know that the question is not very clear and my poor english doesn't let me to explain myself any more so I've made a litle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/G5NCQ/2/).

What I want is that in the seventh line (`return $(this).dialog("option", name, val);`) instead of modifing that (equivalent to `optionsForJQuery.close`) modify `options.close`. That way I will avoid loding the plugins behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">I'm a popup</div>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dialogPlugin = function (options, name, val) {

        var
            // setter function close
            fnClose = null,

            // function when close
            fnMyClose = function() {
                alert("This is plugin's close behavior");
                if (fnClose)
                    fnClose();
            };

        if (options == "option") {
            if (name == "close" && $.isFunction(val)) {
                fnClose = val;
                val = fnMyClose;
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (options.close)
                fnClose = options.close;

            options.close = fnMyClose;
        }

        return (name)
            ? $(this).dialog(options, name, val) //if var == 'undefined'is equal to not send parameters
            : $(this).dialog(options);
    };

})(jQuery);


$("#popup").dialogPlugin({
    close: function() {
        alert("This is user's first close behavior");
    }
});


$("#popup").dialogPlugin("option", "close", function() {
    alert("This is user's second close behavior");
});
```

**EDIT**

or more simple and elegant:

```
(function($){

    var dialog_close = $.ui.dialog.prototype.close;

    $.ui.dialog.prototype.close = function() {

        var self = this;

        alert("This is plugin's close behavior");

        dialog_close.apply(this, arguments);


    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: yeah, I don't delete the "jsfiddle" I don't know what happened